# vertical integrated moisture flux

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, models, atmosphere-modelling

Does anyone know how to calculate the vertical integrated moisture flux using NCL or Grads if you share a NCL script I'm very thankful to you.

Comment: Hi Rojan, welcome to the site. Hopefully the answer linked above is helpful, but otherwise you may need to expand your question a bit to explain a bit more context, if you want a helpful answer.